# java.util.logging.ErrorManager: WRITE_FAILURE when using the "logp" method

Tags: java, oop, logging, websphere

I am trying to log an INFO message as follows:

```
LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, "class", "method", "foo {0}",
                new Object[] { "bar" });
```

This is using [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#logp(java.util.logging.Level,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])) version of logp, using the parameter insertion technique outlined [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/logger.html#the-logp-methods). Doing this, the logger instead outputs an error:

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: WRITE_FAILURE
Error message - Exception occurred when writing to the output stream.
Exception - java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If I instead do this:

```
LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, "class", "method", "foo",
            new Object[] {});
```

I get no error, and "foo" is printed out correctly.  This makes it seem like something is going wrong with the insertion of the parameters into the string.

*Why am I seeing write errors when I try to use the logp method with parameters?*

Comment: Stupid sanity check, can you just verify that the user running the process has the correct permission to read / write to the destination log files, and that the disk is not full?

Comment: Along the same lines, check that the log file wasn't [deleted while the FileHandler was open](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HARMONY-5981).

Comment: This is tagged with websphere, so I'm assuming your code snippet is from an app you're trying to run on the app server.  You don't show how you obtain the LOGGER object in your app, but I've tested your snippet on both Liberty and traditional servers without being able to reproduce the error.

Comment: @MattClark Bit late here (we never resolved the issue), but other logp methods work just fine so we must be set up properly with read/write permissions.